# How to make array elements unique in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In my mongo collection, I have an array where all element have to be unique.
But by mistake, I have added duplicate elements. How can I make array elements distinct?
Is there any query/command?

document in collection:

```
{
   Tags: ["a", "a", "a"]
}
```

But I want:

```
{
  Tags: ["a"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mongo version 4.2+ you can just use [pipelined updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) combined with [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/), like so:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      Tags: {
        $setUnion: "$Tags"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6tKp9BWH2AV)

Comment: just a remark :  This solution is not very suitable if collection is big and there is just few documents with duplicated elements in the Tags array  that need to be updated since it will force update for all collection documents ...

Comment: This is true, there is no way to only update documents with duplicates in them.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique index on the `tag` property of the `collection` in question.

Please refer to the following official guide;

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: How can I remove previously added duplicate elements? I want to keep each element only once.

Comment: You must use $addToSet instead of $push when adding the new element to the array to keep unique values in the array ...

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a nice option to clean duplicates from mongo shell:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "Tags": { "$setUnion": [ "$Tags", [] ] },
        "same": { "$eq": [
        { "$size": "$Tags" },
        { "$size": { "$setUnion": [ "$Tags", [] ] } }
    ]}
  }},
   { "$match": { "same": false } }
 ]).forEach(function(doc) {
 db.collection.update(
    { "_id": doc._id },
    { "$set": { "Tags": doc.Tags } }
  )
 })
```

explained:

1. project a new field "Tags" with only the unique values.
2. Project a new field "same" that will check and say if there is duplicates.
3. Match only the documents having duplicates
4. Loop with forEach over the documents having duplicate tags to replace with the unique version.